# Best practice to observe livedata from data class

Tags: android-livedata, android-lifecycle

I need to observe a LiveData object from a data class. I have observed these two methods are working:

Method 1: Convert the class to a `LifecycleOwner`

```
class MyObservingClass: LifecycleOwner {

    private val lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry
    var receivedData: String = ""

    init {

        lifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)
        Server.dataObject.observe(this) {
            receivedData = it
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "observed : $it")
        }

        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
    }

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        return lifecycleRegistry
    }
}
```

Method 2: Use observeForever

```
class MyObservingClass {

    var receivedData: String = ""

    init {
        Server.dataObject.observeForever {
            receivedData = it
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "observed : $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am using it as `val obj = MyObservingClass()` in some other place. As previously stated both of these approaches are working and I can observe the LiveData.

My question is, **will these two methods prevent garbage collection of the objects as they are observing indefinitely?** Are both these methods flawed? I am making an Android library and don't have life-cycle aware components like Activity.

Thanks for the replies :)